# Entity Framework Add Performance Degrades With More Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, entity-framework

I'll begin this post by noting that I'm entirely new to the .NET world. ASP, EntityFramework, Linq, etc. are all mostly unknown magic at this point.

Having said that, I've built myself a neat Web API chat-like application with SignalR support for real-time events. It works quite well, but I'm having some **performance problems with the Add function.**

In my chat application, there are "Pads" (chat rooms) which contain a number of "Mates" and "Messages". Here's my Pad model for reference:

```
public class Pad
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PadId { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mate> Mates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

My problem lies in my SignalR hub that processes a new Message sent to a particular pad. **These two lines take about half a second to process.**

```
pad.Messages.Add(msg); // pad is the Pad entity already fetched from the db context
db.Messages.Add(msg);
```

But they only take that long when Pad.Messages contains a large number of messages. Thousands. **If I am sending to a pad with few to no messages, it executes almost instantly.**

My initial 'trick' to improve the perceived performance here is to move the adding functions to **after** I send the notification back to the clients, but I realize something like this could present a potential problem later when there are tens or hundreds of thousands of messages in one pad.

Any advice here would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the entire message send method for reference:

```
public void SendMessage(string pad_id, string body)
{
    var user_id = IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(Context.User.Identity);
    body = body.Trim();
    if (body.Length <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Check that the user belongs in this pad...
    var user = (from u in db.Users
                where u.Id == user_id
                select u).First();
    var pad = (from p in user.Pads where p.PadId == new Guid(pad_id) select p).FirstOrDefault();
    if (pad != null) {
        // Save the message to the database
        var msg = new Message()
        {
            MessageId = new Guid(),
            Author = user,
            Body = body,
            SendTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            Pad = pad
        };

        pad.Messages.Add(msg); // These two lines
        db.Messages.Add(msg); // Are the culprit.
        db.SaveChangesAsync();
        Clients.Group(pad_id).messageReceived(user.Id, pad_id, body, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow); // Send message to clients
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I'm on EF 6.0.0

Comment: How are your indexes setup? Usually inserts that are taking a long time in large datasets are due to updating the indexes after each insert.

Comment: In fairness, if you want absolute performance skip the ORM, go with a micro-Orm and hand tweaked sql.

Comment: How do you manage context lifecycle? Do you use fresh context every time, or reuse context in the entire app?

Comment: I re-use the context in the Hub class as an instance variable.
`private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();`

Comment: That's not good. Use new context each time and dispose it after usage.

Comment: Indexes appear to have been set automatically by EF on the foreign keys everywhere. Could this be the culprit? How would I go about attacking that?

Comment: I actually moved the context to an instance var, assuming there'd be overhead in re-instantiating it each time. I'll move it back to a new instance for each method, but this perf issue persists either way.

Comment: Which version on EF do you use?

Comment: I'm on EF6.0.0 installed via NuGet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, all you want to do is add 1 row (Message) to the table.

While constructing the Message entity, just use the padid instead of the Pad object.
That way you don't need to deal with all the pad objects. From a DB perspective, you just need to add a Message row with a PadId key.

```
    var msg = new Message()
    {
        MessageId = new Guid(),
        Author = user,
        Body = body,
        SendTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        PadId = new Guid(pad_id)
    };

    // pad.Messages.Add(msg); // don't need this.
    db.Messages.Add(msg);
```

The above should always insert one row and not depend on the number of messages in the pad.
If it still gives a performance problem, then adding a single row is causing a lot of index updates to your table.

Comment: My Message model doesn't have a PadId, as it references the entire object - I will try removing that first Add and see if the performance improves.

Comment: A couple of ef versions ago, you could add a linked entity as well as a member property for the foreign key. pad entity and padid property.

Comment: Turns out this was the solution. So I don't need to maintain the entity framework representation of the navigational property in a One-To-Many scenario, but out of curiosity, what about in a Many-To-Many situation? I have a Pads to Mates relation where there is an entirely separate table involved (PadMates). Do I have to do something like `pad.Mates.Add(newmate);  mate.Pads.Add(newmate);`? Would that introduce the same performance overhead? And how would I avoid this without manipulating the PadMates relation outside of EF? (there is no EF representation of this table, it's abstracted away).